# [android-studio-2.2]Duplicate package name

Tags: android-studio-2.2

[See The Image！This appears after update to 2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5fvD.jpg)

But In Class A，the package is "com.example.roxas.myapplication.a"

UPDATE：AndroidStudio 2.2.1 is released！After the upgrade the problem has gone ！

Comment: have the same problem after update Android Studio to 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I met when I use Databinding.
If I remove the Databinding config in build.gradle,the problem fixed.

Comment: Oh，that the problem! But I need Databinding...Is this a bug?or wrong config?

Answer (score 0):

**Why you have kept `"com.example.roxas.myapplication.a"` inside `"com.example.roxas.myapplication"`?**

It should be `"a"` instead of `"com.example.roxas.myapplication.a"` in package `"com.example.roxas.myapplication"`

Comment: So,that the problem I met...When I Invalidate Caches/Restart ，It's show like you say. "a" instead of "com.example.roxas.myapplication.a" in package "com.example.roxas.myapplication"。After gradle build finished，the problem come...

Comment: But In Class A，the package is "com.example.roxas.myapplication.a" NOT "com.example.roxas.myapplication.com.example.roxas.myapplication.a"

Comment: I'M saying change your project hierarchy to a only inside com.example.roxas.myapplication which contains class A

Comment: I have the same problem, real package name is correct but Android Studio shows it incorrect

Comment: @Tim Try AndroidStudio 2.2.1